# Objective C Delegate declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

Can someone tell me the difference between

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id  <protocol_name> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController * <protocol_name> delegate;
```

Answer (score 34):

> `@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;`

This specifies that objects of the current class have a delegate that can be of any type. The `weak` specifier is common for delegate objects as it means the object with the delegate does not increment the delegate's reference count (in ARC-speak "keep a strong reference of it"). A `weak` delegate reference is standard practice.

> `@property (nonatomic, weak) id < protocol_name > delegate;`

This specifics that objects of the current class have a delegate that can be of any type (id) but *must* conform to the `protocol_name` protocol. This is particularly useful as the class containing the delegate knows that there are specific messages that it can send to its delegate and "know" that the delegate will respond to them.

> `@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController * < protocol_name > delegate;`

This is the same as the second example except that the delegate must be an object of class `UIViewController`. In practice, `delegate` objects are usually of type `id`, though this is not a requirement - it just offers greater freedom to the programmer.

---

**EDIT: Protocols**

Let's say you declare a class as follows:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject <MyDelegateProtocol>
// ...
@end
```

The `<MyDelegateProtocol>` in this declaration means that `MyObject` implements the methods defined in the `MyDelegateProtocol` protocol (i.e. 'conforms to the protocol').

The protocol definition (previous to the class definition, obviously) may look like this:

```
@protocol MyDelegateProtocol <NSObject>
@required
- (void)method1;
- (void)method2;
@optional
- (void)method3;
@end
```

This means that any object 'conforming' to the `MyDelegateProtocol` protocol **must** implement methods called `-(void)method1` and `-(void)method2`. And, *optionally*, may include an implementation for the message `-(void)method3`.

This is extremely useful information for delegate objects (the protocol name could be anything by the way, I just include the word 'delegate' to make it obvious that it is used as a delegate protocol).

If another class now defines:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyDelegateProtocol> delegate;
```

the class **knows** that it can rely on implementations of `-method1` and `-method2` to be implemented by its delegate, and `-method3` *may* be implemented as well (which it can check with code such as the following:)

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(method3)]) {
    [self.delegate method3];
}
else {
    // Delegate doesn't implement -method3.
}
```

The check is unnecessary for `-method1` and `-method2` as these methods are `@required` by the protocol definition, and it can call them whenever it wants.

A class can also use more than one protocol at a time (e.g. `<Proto1, Proto2, UITableViewDelegate>`) - for a more complete overview of Protocols, check out the [Apple Docs on protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot , but does the first declaration mean that objects of the class 'need not' conform to the protocol since I haven't used <protocol_name> ??

Comment: @Pr33tham, correct, the first property (just using `id`) doesn't need anything (and you need to check before calling any method)

Comment: I am using XCode 6.2. To declare a delegate of type UIViewController, the right format is `UIViewController < protocol_name > *delegate`.

Answer (score 6):

> @property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;

A property with no specific type or protocol implementation. When calling methods on `delegate`, anything goes - the compiler will trust you if it can see that a method exists somewhere and the runtime will check if you were lying.

> @property (nonatomic, weak) id < protocol_name > delegate;

A property with no specific type, but which implements a specified protocol. You can only call methods from that protocol (unless you do some casting). Any instance that is set to the property must conform to the protocol (or again, you need some casting).

> @property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController * < protocol_name > delegate;

A property with a specific type (`UIViewController`) and which implements a specified protocol. You can only call methods from that protocol and from the `UIViewController` class (unless you do some casting). Any instance that is set to the property must conform to the protocol and be a subclass of `UIViewController` (or again, you need some casting).

Answer (score 1):

In the first example:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;
```

you create a property of type id which is 'any' type in objective c with name - delegate.

The second example:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id < protocol_name > delegate;
```

you create a property of type id which needs to conform to protocol_name protocol with name - delegate.

The last example:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController * < protocol_name > delegate;
```

you create a property of type UIViewController (pointer to UIViewController) which needs to conform to protocol_name protocol with name - delegate.