# Cannot find delegate defined in another header

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates

I have a very simple problem, yet because it's so simple, I can't find anything wrong with it to fix.

ListSelectorUtility.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ListSelectorDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) returnValueString:(NSString *)value requestID:(long)requestID;

@end

@interface ListSelectorUtility : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *data;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ListSelectorDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic) long requestID;

@end
```

UpdateProperty.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ListSelectorUtility.h"

@interface UpdateProperty : UITableViewController <ListSelectorDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *data;

@end
```

There's an error on the `@interface UpdateProperty : UITableViewController <ListSelectorDelegate>` saying that `No type or protocol named 'ListSelectorDelegate'`. Why is this happened? How to solve this? Thanks.

EDIT: oh, and when I do CMD+click on the `<ListSelectorDelegate>`, it brings me straight up to the `ListSelectorDelegate` declaration. That means the IDE (supposedly) can find it.

Comment: Have you implement the delegate method in UpdateProperty controller ?

Comment: @Pushpa yeah I do have.

Comment: I hope this link may helps you
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23106744/3515115

Comment: check did u imported  `#import "UpdateProperty.h"` in `ListSelectorUtility.h` file if added this remove this line `#import "UpdateProperty.h`

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya thanks, the link certainly did teach me something I don't know. But in this case, the error is not on the declaration of the property, but in the declaration of the class, so it is (may) not applicable.

Comment: @Shan I have. In the `ListSelectorUtility.h`, there's only #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>, nothing else.

Comment: okay finally try this, add this line `@protocol ListSelectorDelegate;` in `UpdateProperty.h` file `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ListSelectorUtility.h"
@protocol ListSelectorDelegate;`

Comment: @ChenLiYong did u tried as i suggested .?

Comment: @Shan yes, I have. Still doesn't work. It's finally work though, after I rearrange and cleaning import structure (that was plenty of work), and I think there might be some import conflict between the headers so the protocol command is not processed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

set property of delegate (strong) on ListSelectorUtility.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<ListSelectorDelegate> delegate;
```

may bey problem of that because if it is week then dealloc by ARC and call the delegate method on ListSelectorUtility.h on your pass the data and values

```
[self.delegate returnValueString:obj_StringValue requestID:obj_requestID];
```

And finally this delegate method declare in UpdateProperty.h,

```
- (void) returnValueString:(NSString *)value requestID:(long)requestID
{
  //---------
  //Your Code
  //---------
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I have changed the `weak` to `strong` now but the problem persist. The error here shows up at build time, not at runtime.

Comment: try full clean (cmd+shift+k) then build

Comment: Done. Did the full clean, and then build. The error is still there, and prevent me to build further..

Comment: I have done them all. ;_; I have called the delegate method in the child, and I have declared the method in the parent. I also have created several delegates in past for other purposes, and all went fine. Only this went wrong for no reason. ;_;